# How to change camera info in Exif using command line

Tags: command-line, exif

I have analog camera and I give a film to the lab where they scan it, I wanted to upload it to flickr but want to change info about camera. Right now it's `NORITSU KOKI QSS-32_33` and I wanted it to be `pentax k1000` (I don't want to clear exif data). How can I do this from command line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tool you're looking for is called exiftool. You can use it to read & write exif meta data that's attached to a single image or a whole directories worth of files using its recursive switch (`-r`).

To change the camera model you can use the `-model=".."` switch.

#### Example

Here's an image before the change.

```
$ exiftool ff42403138dd5fa56e38efdaab2ced1435d0e28c.jpg 
ExifTool Version Number         : 9.27
File Name                       : ff42403138dd5fa56e38efdaab2ced1435d0e28c.jpg
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 2.1 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2013:12:31 14:18:44-05:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2013:12:31 14:18:44-05:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2013:12:31 14:18:44-05:00
File Permissions                : rw-------
File Type                       : JPEG
MIME Type                       : image/jpeg
JFIF Version                    : 1.01
Resolution Unit                 : None
X Resolution                    : 1
Y Resolution                    : 1
Comment                         : CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v80), quality = 95.
Image Width                     : 50
Image Height                    : 50
Encoding Process                : Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
Bits Per Sample                 : 8
Color Components                : 3
Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling            : YCbCr4:2:0 (2 2)
Image Size                      : 50x50
```

To change the model of my camera.

```
$ exiftool -model="sam's camera" ff42403138dd5fa56e38efdaab2ced1435d0e28c.jpg
```

Now when we recheck the tags.

```
$ exiftool ff42403138dd5fa56e38efdaab2ced1435d0e28c.jpg 
ExifTool Version Number         : 9.27
File Name                       : ff42403138dd5fa56e38efdaab2ced1435d0e28c.jpg
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 2.3 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2013:12:31 14:19:14-05:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2013:12:31 14:19:14-05:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2013:12:31 14:19:14-05:00
File Permissions                : rw-------
File Type                       : JPEG
MIME Type                       : image/jpeg
JFIF Version                    : 1.01
Exif Byte Order                 : Big-endian (Motorola, MM)
Camera Model Name               : sam's camera
X Resolution                    : 1
Y Resolution                    : 1
Resolution Unit                 : None
Y Cb Cr Positioning             : Centered
Comment                         : CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v80), quality = 95.
Image Width                     : 50
Image Height                    : 50
Encoding Process                : Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
Bits Per Sample                 : 8
Color Components                : 3
Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling            : YCbCr4:2:0 (2 2)
Image Size                      : 50x50
```

There is another tool called `exiv2` which does the same kinds of things as `exiftool` in case you're interested.

#### References

- [exiv2 website](http://www.exiv2.org/)
- [ExifTool website](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/)