# How to list all image files with a certain rating (recorded in XMP data)

Tags: bash, images, exif

I have a directory with a large list of image files (JPG). Some of them have a specific rating, which is recorded as [XMP data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform). An example would be

> XMP Exif > xmp:Rating = 5

(for a file that has 5 stars).

I would like to select all files in bash that have a certain rating, and then move/copy them to a specific directory. I have found some roundabout ways using e.g. [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822693/read-image-xmp-data-in-python) or [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578169/how-can-i-read-xmp-data-from-a-jpg-with-php) but am wondering if there could be a more straightforward way?

Comment: I'm not sure how I can pass relevant arguments to the move/copy command. cp .... WHAT .... to copy those files? It seems that the XMP details are not available in bash, at least not that easily, so I don't know how I can use them as arguments when copying, .

Comment: OK thanks, I hoped I could do it without a separate script but I'll look into this then.

Comment: You could also test if this work for you, [exiftool](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107327/how-to-change-camera-info-in-exif-using-command-line) I don't have it and I don't have any xmp metadata available, if you can get using only this command the rating, then it could worth writing a shell script with this.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it!

Comment: Also `exiv2` is available for install for linux. Basically, if you test any of them works for you, you can update the question with the exact output you get from something like <exiv2 -ps OR exiftool> file.jpg | grep Rating and you can use this output in a simple script to get all the files copy/move them.